# NGINX Upstream servers in order

Tags: nginx, proxy, backup, fallback

I have an NGINX proxy with 4 upstream servers behind it, 2 local, 2 remote, this is to maintain the maximum failure tolerance possible.
Now I can make it try each server in order with something like this

```
upstream backend {
    server server1;
    server 127.0.0.1:8081 backup;
}

upstream fallback1 {
    server server2;
    server 127.0.0.1:8082 backup;
}

upstream fallback2 {
    server server3;
    server server4 backup;
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504 http_403;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8081;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://fallback1;
        proxy_next_upstream invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504 http_403;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8082;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://fallback2;
        proxy_next_upstream invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504 http_403;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?  As to get to the remote servers I'm looping back through the servers for a third time which feels wrong.

I want nginx to avoid using the remote servers if the local ones have the data as this would incur a cost.

I also don't mind if 100% of requests went to one server if the server was responding.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you merge your backups and primaries into a single consolidated entry - and also, to speed up subsequent requests, that you look into keepalives.  This would prevent additional TCP handshake overhead.

```
upstream backend {
    server server1;
    server server2;
    server server3 backup;
    server server4 backup;
    keepalive 25;
}


server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1; 
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504 http_403;
    }
}
```

In the above configuration, the first two servers will be tried in a round-robin configuration, then the backup servers will be tried.

I would also explore [max_fails and fail_timeout](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html?&_ga=2.166774142.1767464860.1621535179-1532811495.1618508066#server) which can be appended to the upstream servers for a way of dealing with failures in the upstream list.  Proxy_next_upstream can also be configured to move to the next upstream upon the "[timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream)" condition.

More about keepalives [in NGINX documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html?&_ga=2.166774142.1767464860.1621535179-1532811495.1618508066#keepalive)